# Can't access values from one stage to another stage in MongoDB aggregate pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to implement aggregate pipeline in my existing application.
I have used two `$group` and want to get first `$group` value to `$project`.

```
db.getCollection('activities').aggregate([{
    $match: {
        'event': 'PAGE',
        'cid': {
            '$in': ['16586']
        },
        'payload.pageId': {
            '$exists': true,
            '$ne': null
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            pageId: '$payload.pageId',
                    user: '$uid'
        },
                users:{$sum:1}//want this users value in `$project` stage

                },
        $group: {
        _id: {
            pageId: '$payload.pageId',
                    status: '$payload.status'
        },
                counts:{$sum:1},
    }
}
    ,
{$project:{users:1,pageId:'$_id.pageId',counts:1,status:'$_id.status',_id:0}},
{$match:{status:'complete'}}
])
```

Comment: Are you trying to group on `pageId` and `status` and trying to get `users` count and `counts` ?

Comment: yes,exactly the same